# Showing that $\frac{(j+a)!(j-a)!}{a^2}$, for $a=1, \ldots, j$, reaches its minimum at $a\approx \sqrt{j}$

Tags: calculus, number-theory, discrete-mathematics, optimization, factorial

Let $j$ be a positive integer, and $a=1,\dots,j$. From numerical result, I get that $$\frac{(j+a)!(j-a)!}{a^2}$$ reaches its minimum at $a\approx\sqrt{j}$. But how to prove this?

More general form: [$\alpha \neq 2$ case](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4038988/where-does-a-i-prod-t-1j-t-alpha-i-alpha-reach-its-the-minimum)

Comment: Let $x_a=\frac{(j+a)!(j-a)!}{a^2}$ and consider $\frac{x_a}{x_{a+1}}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $$f(a)=\frac{(j+a)!\,(j-a)!}{a^2}\qquad \text{and} \qquad g(a)=\log[f(a)]$$
$$g'(a)=\frac {f'(a)}{f(a)}$$ Simplify to show that
$$f'(a)=0 \implies H_{j+a}-H_{j-a}-\frac{2}{a}=0$$
Suppose that $j \gg a$ and use the asymptotics of harmonic numbers; it gives
$$H_{j+a}-H_{j-a}-\frac{2}{a}=-\frac{2}{a}+\frac{2 a}{j}-\frac{a}{j^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{j^3}\right)$$ If you use the expansion to $O\left(\frac{1}{j^2}\right)$, it gives your result. Using the next term would give, as better approximation
$$a \sim \frac{j\sqrt{2} }{\sqrt{2 j-1}}$$

Using more terms and series reversion,
$$a=\sqrt j \left(1+\frac{1}{12 j}+\frac{71}{1440 j^2}+\frac{2951}{34560 j^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{j^4}\right)\right)\tag 1$$

Trying for $j=16$, the above truncated series gives
$$a=\frac{28465051}{7077888}\approx 4.021687$$ while the solution given by Newton method is $4.021616$

**Edit**

Using $(1)$, we could easily show that
$$H_{j+a}-H_{j-a}-\frac{2}{a}=\frac{3463}{12096\,j^{7/2}}+O\left(\frac{1}{j^{9/2}}\right)$$ Knowing the possible form of $a$, let
$$a=\sqrt j \,\,\sum _{i=0}^3 \frac {b_i} { j^{i}}$$ This leads to
$$a=\sqrt j \left(1+\frac{1}{12 j}+\frac{71}{1440 j^2}+\frac{491}{5760j^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{j^4}\right)\right)\tag 2$$ This changed very little coefficient $b_3$

$$\frac{2951}{34560}-\frac{491}{5760}=\frac{1}{6912}$$ but this is sufficient to make
$$H_{j+a}-H_{j-a}-\frac{2}{a}=-\frac{4429051}{1036800\,j^{9/2}}+O\left(\frac{1}{j^{11/2}}\right)$$

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

**Approximation of the factorial**

Observe that
$$\log N!=\sum_{n=1}^{N}\log n\approx \int\limits_{1}^{N}\log x\,\mathrm{d}x = N\log N-N+1\approx N\log N-N.$$
Raising both sides to $e$ yields
$$N!\approx\left(\frac{N}{e}\right)^N.$$
One may even use Stirlings formula but at the end we'll see that this approximation is more than enough.

**Replacing**

If we replace the factorial in your formula with this approximation we have
$$\frac{1}{a^2}\left(\frac{j+a}{e}\right)^{j+a}\left(\frac{j-a}{e}\right)^{j-a}=\frac{1}{a^2}e^{-2j}\left(j+a\right)^{j+a}\left(j-a\right)^{j-a}.$$
The domain of this function is $\{x\in\mathbb{R}\mid j>a.\}$

**Setting up the equation**

In order to find the minimum we have to compute the derivative of this function and set it equal to zero
$$-\frac{2}{a^2}e^{-2j}\left(j+a\right)^{j+a}\left(j-a\right)^{j-a}+\frac{1}{a^2}e^{-2j}\left(j+a\right)^{j+a}\left(j-a\right)^{j-a}(\log(j-a)+1)+\frac{2}{a^2}e^{-2j}\left(j+a\right)^{j+a}\left(j-a\right)^{j-a}(\log(j+a)+1)=0.$$
**Solving the equation**

1. Write the left hand side as a single fraction. $$\frac{1}{a^2}e^{-2j}(j+a)^{j+a}(j-a)^{j-a}(\log(j+a)+\log(j-a))=0$$
2. Multiply both sides by $a^2e^{2j}(j-a)^a$. $$(j+a)^{j+a}(j-a)^{j}(\log(j+a)+\log(j-a))=0$$
3. Now we have $3$ different possibilities:

> *P1:* $(j-a)^j=0$. Violates $j>a$.

> *P2:* $(j+a)^{j+a}=0$. Base has to be $0$ but $0^0$ is undefined.

> *P3:* $\log(j+a)+\log(j-a)=0$. Is solvable.

**Solving P3**

Combine logarithms
$$\log((j+a)(j-a))=0 \Rightarrow (j+a)(j-a)=1.$$
Expand out the terms and add $a^2$ on both sides to find the minimum.
$$j^2=a^2+1\Rightarrow j=\sqrt{a^2+1}.$$
The equation above *does not* have $2$ solutions since our domain was $\{x\in\mathbb{R}\mid j>a\}$ (=no negative solution). Equivalently
$$a=\sqrt{j^2-1}.$$
This is as good as $a=j$, since for big values of $j$ we may even say $j>6$, the difference is very small. For $j\to\infty$ there is no difference.

Comment: Wow that's very helpful! Thank you very much!

Comment: Actually, a should be approximately $\sqrt{j}$ from numerical result. So maybe the first derivative equals 0 gives us the maximum instead of the minimum. I suppose

Comment: Don't worry it is the minimum.